# MetaPost vardef: how to declare a variable of type 'expr'?

Tags: macros, metapost, variable, definition, declare

I want to make a macro `swap`:

```
vardef swap(expr a, b) = 
save tmp;
expr tmp;
tmp := a;
a := b;
b := tmp;
enddef;
```

But there is an error when compilating:

```
! A statement can't begin with `expr'.
```

I thought I could declare a `tmp` variable of type `expr`... I intended to swap variables of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `expr` variable type. You want `suffix a,b`, not `expr`. And you need to declare `tmp` to be the same type as `a` (or `b`, of course).

```
vardef swap(suffix a,b)=
  save tmp;
  if numeric a: numeric tmp;
  elseif pair a: pair tmp;
  elseif path a: pair tmp;
  elseif transform a: transform tmp;
  elseif color a: color tmp;
  elseif cmykcolor a: cmykcolor tmp;
  elseif string a: string tmp;
  elseif boolean a: boolean tmp;
  elseif picture a: picture tmp;
  elseif pen a: pen tmp;
  fi
  tmp:=b;
  b:=a;
  a:=tmp;
enddef;

pair u;u=(1,0);
pair v;v=(0,1);

swap(u,v);

show u;show v;

end
```

Console output:

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.01 (TeX Live 2021) (kpathsea version 6.3.3)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./swap.mp
>> (0,1)
>> (1,0) )
Transcript written on swap.log.
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain the difference between ```expr``` and ```suffix```? Before this case, I was usually enough with ```expr``` only. I've just looked through MetaPost manual and did not find the exact answer to my question.

Comment: @Vladimir As far as I remember, any variable is an instance of a `suffix`. Basically, if you declare `expr a,b`, then the code would use the *values* of the variables, not the variables, so `tmp:=a` would be legal but not `a:=b`.

Comment: Ah, understood. If we need to change the variable given to a function, then we use ```suffix```. If we need just a value, then it must be ```expr```. So that is why ```suffix``` is used in ```vardef incr suffix $ = $:=$+1; $ enddef;``` in plain.mp: ```incr()``` macro changes the given variable.